# Sheafification - Construction of a Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I tried different books and lecture notes to understand sheafification, but for instance in Hartshore or Shafarevich's book, but I found it hard to understand.
The following is the approach my professor used. But also here I have some questions. But first here is what he wrote:

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf.

$$\mathscr{F}^g(U):= \left\{\begin{array}{rl} \{f_P\}_{P\in U}| & f_P\in\mathscr{F}_P, \forall P\in U\textrm{ }\exists V\ni P, V\subset U\textrm{ and a }f\in\mathscr{F}(V) \\
         | & \textrm{ with }f\in\mathscr{F}(V)\to\mathscr{F}_Q, f\mapsto f_Q \end{array}\right\}$$

First see that $\mathscr{F}^g$ is a presheaf:
Let $U'\subset U$. $f=\{f_P\}_{P\in U}\in\mathscr{F}^g(U)\mapsto \bar{f}:=\{f_P\}_{P\in U'}\in\mathscr{F}^g(U')$.
So $\forall P\in U'$ $\exists V\subset U'$ such that $V'=V\cap U'$ and $\mathscr{F}(U)\to\mathscr{F}_Q$ with $f\mapsto f_Q$.

$$\begin{array}{ccc} \mathscr{F}(V) & & \\ \downarrow{\varphi} & \searrow &  & \\ \mathscr{F}_Q & \xleftarrow{} & \mathscr{F}(V')& \end{array}$$
For all $Q\in V'$. and $\varphi(\bar{f})$

Let $U=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_i$.

1. $\mathscr{F}^g(U)\overset{\beta}{\to}\prod\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}^g(U_i)$
2. $\prod\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}^g(U_i)\overset{\alpha}{\to}\prod\limits_{i,j\in I}\mathscr{F}^g(U_{ij})$, ($U_{ij}=U_i\cap U_j$) with $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}\mapsto \{f_{ij}\}_{ij}$,

   and $f_{ij} = \rho_{U_i U_{ij}}f_i - \rho_{U_j U_{ij}}f_j$ and $f_i = \{f_{iP}\}_{P\in U_i}\in\mathscr{F}^g(U_i)$

   $(*)$ $Im(\beta)=ker(\alpha)$. If $\beta(f)=0$ $\Rightarrow f_P=0$ $\forall P\in U$ $\Rightarrow f = \{f_P\}_{P\in U}=0$.
   $(**)$ If $P\in U_{ij}$, then $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}\in ker(\alpha)$.

Show $f_{ip}=f_{jp}$: Let $U_i\supseteq V_i\ni f\in V_j\subseteq U_j$
$\mathscr{F}(V_i)\to \mathscr{F}_{iP}$ with $\tilde{f}_i\mapsto f_{iP}$ and $\mathscr{F}(V_j)\to \mathscr{F}_{jP}$ with $\tilde{f}_j\mapsto f_{jP}$.

$(***)$ $\rho_{U_i U_{ij}}f_i = \rho_{U_j U_{ij}}f_j\Rightarrow f_{ip}=f_{jp}$ $\forall P\in U_{ij}$.
$\tilde{f}=\{f_{P}\}_{P\in U}$. $f_P=f_{iP}$ for $i$ with $P\in U_i$.
$\tilde{f}\in\mathscr{F}^g(U)$ fulfils the condition, and so $\mathscr{F}^g$ is a sheaf.
Our definition for a sheaf: Let $\mathscr{F}: ouv(X)\to \textrm{(abelian groups)}$ be a presheaf.
Then $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf if $\forall U\subset X$ open:
$U=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_i$ open couver $\Rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)\overset{\beta}{\to}\prod\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}(U_i)$ is injective and $Im(\beta)=\{(f_i)_{i\in I}|\rho_{U_i U_{ij}} f_i = \rho_{U_j U_{ij}} f_j\}$.

Now my questions:

To $(*)$: Here we want to show that  $Im(\beta)=ker(\alpha)$ holds right?  But how did he show it? I don't understand what he does to afterwards.

To $(**)$: Why do we have ''If $P\in U_{ij}$, then $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}\in ker(\alpha)$.''?
 
To $(***)$: I understand why ''$f_{ip}=f_{jp}$'' follows, but not that ''$\rho_{U_i U_{ij}}f_i = \rho_{U_j U_{ij}}f_j$'' holds.

Thanks and all the best!

Comment: I'll let someone with a bit more patience read through your construction. Just one comment, hopefully helpful. This is one of those things that you shouldn't get too caught up on. I know the idea of something existing without understanding it's construction is a little scary, but you've done it before, and you'll do it again. Do you think about $M\otimes_R N$ as the free module on $M\times N$ modulo the relations of bilinearity? No, you think about $M\otimes_R N$ as being an object that exchanges bilinear maps for linear ones. Similarly, one rarely thinks about the sheafification via

Comment: it's explicit construction. Instead one thinks of it as the "sheaf closure" of a presheaf--one for which all other maps to sheaves factor through. So, understand this construction once, but don't try and remember it precisely, or your head might explode (outside of the "it's a system of compatible stalks" mantra).

Comment: hahaha ok :D But how is it if I have to explain sheafification i.e. in an exam. Or should I better try to understand an explicit example? Thanks!

Comment: Try "Qing Liu - Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves", pag. $36$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\mathcal{F}^g$ is a presheaf.
In order to show that it is a sheaf we need to show that for ervery open set $U$ and every covering $\{U_i\}$ then
[image]
is an equalizer. The two maps
$$ \prod_i \mathcal{F} ^g (U_i) \longrightarrow \prod_{i,j} \mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i,j}) $$
are induced by the two different restrictions into $\mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i,j})$ *i.e.* $\mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i,j})$ and $\mathcal{F} ^g (U_{j}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i,j})$.
If $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups or rings or some other "nice" algebraic object this is the same as showing that
$$ 0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^g(U) \overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow}  \prod_i \mathcal{F} ^g (U_i) \overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \prod_{i,j} \mathcal{F} ^g (U_{i,j})  $$
is exact with the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you defined.

I guess that $(*)$ should be $Ker(\beta)=0$ and this is in fact what is shown.

Next we want to show that $Im(\beta) = Ker(\alpha)$.
First $Im(\beta) \subset Ker(\alpha)$. This is $(***)$: starting with $f \in \mathcal{F}^g(U)$ we can restrict it to $U_{i,j}$ in two different ways, first to $U_i$ and then to $U_{i,j}$ or first to $U_{j}$ and then to $U_{i,j}$.
However both are the same since anyway we look at it it is just restricting from $U$ to $U_{i,j}$.
Next $Im(\beta) \supset Ker(\alpha)$.
This is $(**)$.
Let $\{f_i\} \in Ker(\alpha)$. That is $\rho_{U_i U_{i,j}}f_i - \rho_{U_j U_{i,j}}f_j=0$ for every $i,j$. For every point $P \in U_{i,j}$ we have an equality $(f_i)_P=(f_j)_P$ in the stalk $\mathcal{F}^g_P=\mathcal{F}_P$. So there is a neighborhood of $P \subset V_{i,j,P} \subset U_{i,j}$ and an element  $\tilde{f}_{i,j,P}$ such that for every point $Q \in V_{i,j,P}$ the restriction to the stalk is $(\tilde{f}_{i,j,P})_Q=(f_i)_Q=(f_j)_Q$.
Now we can define an element of $\mathcal{F} ^g (U)$ as $\tilde{f}=\{(f_i)_P\}$. By construction $\tilde{f} \in Im(\beta)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for working through my question and for this perfect answer :)